# Not able to read XML file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML File and an HTML under htdocs of the apache that I've set up locally in my machine.

I'm trying to read that xml file, but I'm not getting any response. It's not even alerting the status. Also if I give invalid file name, it isn't showing any difference. The xml file is valid. Can anyone tell me where I'm missing.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('hey');
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "feedTest.xml",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        alert(status);
        }

    });
$("#output").append("Some Text");
});   

function parseXML(xml){
    $(xml).find("mainPage").each(function(){
        console.log("I'm in");
        $("#output").append($(this).attr("time") + "<br/>");
    });
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="output">
    Hello
</div>
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
Comments
 -->

<dashboard>
<mainPage time="20">
    <horizontal>2</horizontal>
    <vertical>3</vertical>
    <loop set="true"></loop>
    <files>
        <name time="10">a</name>
        <name time="10">b</name>            
    </files>
</mainPage> 
</dashboard>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an error handler to your $.ajax request with an alert to see what comes back?

Comment: @dSquared Thanks for the idea. I tried, and got this:[Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 6"  data: no]

Comment: Sounds like a cross-domain issue, is the XML file on the same domain at the same port as the script calling it?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's working now. I think it was something to do with the editor. I had done a 'save as' on the file earlier. And now I closed it. It started working. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as dSquared noted, check what comes back to your request - I would recommend som developer tools inside broswer, where you can see every request and response.

If there is no difference with invalid file name, check your paths - is your `"feedTest.xml"` really in the same directory as your page with your script?

Comment: Yes, I can access feedTest.xml from the browser in the same position.

Comment: do you use AdBlock in your browser?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's working now. I think it was something to do with the editor. I had done a 'save as' on the file earlier. And now I closed it. It started working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "feedTest.xml",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){


    $(xml).find("mainPage").each(function(){
        console.log("I'm in");
        $("#output").append($(this).attr("time") + "<br/>");
    });


        }

    });

});
```

function parse xml is redundant, and it was outside success handler (it wasn't called). EDIT: you can use it on this way, however:

.....

```
success: function(xml){
        alert(status);
        parseXML(xml);
        }
```

....